# Updating Schema Containing a Number

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I'm currently facing a concern regarding finding and updating a document field containing a number. I've tried finding and updating fields that are not number values, and it works completely fine, I am most likely just missing a code line.

My main code is the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const database = require('../../database');
const warnsSchema = require('../../schemas/warns-schema')

module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "Test Command",
    async run(client, message, args, Discord){

        const main_chat = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch=>ch.name==="main_chat")
        const sentIn = message.channel.id
        const CaseNumber = args[0]
        const reason = args.join(" ")

        if(sentIn != main_chat) return;
        await database().then(async database => {
            try{

                const results = await warnsSchema.updateOne({
                    "Warning.CaseNumber": CaseNumber
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "Warning.$.Reason": reason
                    }
                })

                console.log(results)

            } finally {
                database.connection.close()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

My current schema is the following:

```
const database = require('mongoose')

const warnsSchema = database.Schema({
    Username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Warning: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    CaseNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = database.model('punishments', warnsSchema)
```

As an example, if I were to replace

```
const results = await warnsSchema.updateOne({
    "Warning.CaseNumber": CaseNumber
},
{
     $set: {
         "Warning.$.Reason": reason
     }
})
```

With

```
const results = await warnsSchema.updateOne({
    "Warning.Reason": CaseNumber
},
{
     $set: {
         "Warning.$.WarnedBy": reason
     }
})
```

The values would be changed properly, and I'd be able to move on. Though as soon as I change it to `"Warning.CaseNumber"`, the code stops working as it should, it does not crash, it simply does not edit any document.

As of right now, I've got the `CaseNumber` set as a constant for the first argument after the command, and the `reason` should be the new reason to replace the previous one with.

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is coming across this same issue, I've made a silly mistake. You must specify that a certain argument is a number for it to be recognized as an actual number.
Example: `Number(args[0])`